# QT-Creator: where should I see the output of the qMake variable: "message( string )"

Tags: qt-creator, qmake

I am working with `qMake CONFIQ variable` in Qt-creator. I would like to display a message for whether I am in the debug or in the release mode. So, I edited my `.pro file` as follow:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release){
    message("debug mode")
} else {
    message("release mode")
}
```

and according to [THIS](http://www.kde.gr.jp/~ichi/qt/qmake-manual-6.html), the message "is output to the ***console*** and processing of the project file carries on". Till now, I am just guessing this "***console***" would be my Qt-Creator ***Application Output*** tab. if I am right, then something is wrong as I don't see any messages when I compile my project. if I am wrong, then where these messages should be displayed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see the messages on **Compile Output** tab. Please keep in mind that these messages are displayed when you run qmake and not when you compile your project.

Comment: aha, you are right.. when I just run qmake, I can now see the messages on the **Compile Output**, thanks. But, if I may ask, why is it showing me three messages as (Project MESSAGE: debug mode), (Project MESSAGE: debug mode) and (Project MESSAGE: release mode). And, given that I am building in a debug mode, why the message : (Project MESSAGE: release mode) is shown ?

Comment: @hashDefine Unfortunately, I do not know. I have just tried it and got three messages as you have. I've checked the doc but found no explanation. Then went to see the Makefile generated and instead of one I found three files: Makefile, Makefile.Debug and Makefile.Release. Looks like when you run qmake the .pro file is processed 3 times in order to generate the 3 Makefiles. (I am on Windows with Visual Studio 2010.)